# Scala parser combinators for language embedded in html or text (like php)

Tags: scala, embedded-language, parser-combinators

I have been playing around with Scala parser combinators for some time now, and learned  some of the ways to make it behave nicely and do the most of the things I want, using the built in function.

But how do you make an embedded language (like php or ruby's erb)?
It requires whitespace to not be ignored, outside the embedding of real code.

I managed to make a simple parser that matches all text up to a given regex match, but I am looking for a better, prettier way of doing this. There is propably some already defined function that does the stuff needed.

The test language parses text like:

```
now: [[ millis; ]]
and now: [[; millis; ]]
```

and is generated by the following code:

```
package test

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
import scala.util.matching.Regex

sealed abstract class Statement
case class Print(s: String) extends Statement
case class Millis() extends Statement

object SimpleLang extends RegexParsers {

  def until(r: Regex): Parser[String] = new Parser[String]{
    def apply(in: Input) = {
      val source = in.source
      val offset = in.offset
      val start = offset
      (r.findFirstMatchIn( source.subSequence(offset, source.length) )) match {
        case Some(matched) => 
          Success(source.subSequence(offset, offset + matched.start).toString, in.drop(matched.start))
        case None => 
          Failure("string matching regex `"+ r +"' expected but `"+ in.first +"' found", in.drop(0))
      }
    }
  }

  def until(s: String): Parser[String] = until(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(s).r)

  def interpret(stats: List[Statement]): Unit = stats match {
    case Print(s) :: rest => {
      print(s)
      interpret(rest)
    }
    case Millis() :: rest => {
      print(System.currentTimeMillis)
      interpret(rest)
    }
    case Nil => ()
  }

  def apply(input: String) : List[Statement] = parseAll(beginning, input) match {
    case Success(tree,_) => tree
    case e: NoSuccess => throw new RuntimeException("Syntax error: " + e)
  }

  /** GRAMMAR **/

  def beginning = (
    "[[" ~> stats |
    until("[[") ~ "[[" ~ stats ^^ { 
      case s ~ _ ~ ss => Print(s) :: ss
    }
  )

  def stats = rep1sep(stat, ";")

  def stat = (
    "millis" ^^^ { Millis() } |
    "]]" ~> ( (until("[[") <~ "[[") | until("\\z".r)) ^^ {
      case s => Print(s)
    }
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val tree = SimpleLang("now: [[ millis; ]]\nand now: [[; millis; ]]")
    println(tree)
    interpret(tree)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scala's RegexParsers trait provides an implicit conversion from Regex to Parser[Char] which skips any leading whitespace before checking for a regex match.  You can use

```
override val skipWhitespace = false
```

to turn this behavior off, or override the `whiteSpace` member (it's another regex) to provide your own custom string.

These options work globally, turning off the whitespace-skipping means that ALL regex productions will see the whitespace.

Another option would be to avoid using the regex conversion for just a few cases where you need whitespace.  I've done so [here](http://github.com/dwins/geoscript.scala/blob/geocss/geocss/src/main/scala/CssParser.scala#L40) in a parser for CSS which ignores comments in most places, but just before a rule it needs to read them to extract some javadoc-style metadata.

Comment: I am aware of the skipWhitespace possibility, but i was hoping for a cleaner solution (like a lib function i somehow missed). I will check it out. Maybe the cleanest solution involves a preparsing where the text is converted to a print text function of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a lexer before the parser?

Comment: Yes. But I would have to write one my self. The lexer for scala parser combinators throw away whitespace, so it is not suited for code embedded in text.

Comment: @Otey AFAIK, you can control whether it throws away whitespace or not.