# Parsing a blank / whitespace with RegexParsers

Tags: regex, scala, parser-combinators

What is the problem with parsing the blank/whitespace?

```
scala> object BlankParser extends RegexParsers {
         def blank: Parser[Any] = " "
         def foo: Parser[Any] = "foo"
       }
defined module BlankParser

scala> BlankParser.parseAll(BlankParser.foo, "foo")
res15: BlankParser.ParseResult[Any] = [1.4] parsed: foo

scala> BlankParser.parseAll(BlankParser.blank, " ")
res16: BlankParser.ParseResult[Any] =
[1.2] failure: ` ' expected but ` ' found


 ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the lexer for scala throws blankspaces away. 
try 
    override val skipWhitespace = false
to avoid this.

the question was already solved so it seems...
[Scala parser combinators for language embedded in html or text (like php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347552/scala-parser-combinators-for-language-embedded-in-html-or-text-like-php)