# Understanding `not` in Parser Combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I wrote the following Parser with the intent of `fail`-ing on whitespace:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object Foo extends JavaTokenParsers { 
  val wsTest = not(whiteSpace) // uses whitespace inherited from `RegexParsers`
}
```

Why is parsing a bunch of whitespace successfull?

```
scala> Foo.parseAll(Foo.wsTest, "          ")
res5: Foo.ParseResult[Unit] = [1.11] parsed: ()

scala> res5.successful
res6: Boolean = true
```

Looking at `Parsers#not` from the [project](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators), I would've expected a `Failure` for my above test.

```
  /** Wrap a parser so that its failures and errors become success and
   *  vice versa -- it never consumes any input.
   */
  def not[T](p: => Parser[T]): Parser[Unit] = Parser { in =>
    p(in) match {
      case Success(_, _)  => Failure("Expected failure", in)
      case _              => Success((), in)
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `not` works correctly. My guess is that the parser skips white spaces by default and you have to disable that. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564094/parsing-a-blank-whitespace-with-regexparsers

Comment: `My guess is that the parser skips white spaces by default ` - I've observed this behavior with a class extending `JavaTokenParsers`. However, I would not have expected `Foo.parseAll(Foo.wsTest, "     ")` to have succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaTokenParsers extends RegexParsers, RegexParsers has:

```
 protected val whiteSpace = """\s+""".r

 def skipWhitespace = whiteSpace.toString.length > 0

 implicit def regex(r: Regex): Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    ... 
    val start = handleWhiteSpace(source, offset)
    ...
 }

 protected def handleWhiteSpace(source: java.lang.CharSequence, offset: Int): Int =
   if (skipWhitespace)
     (whiteSpace findPrefixMatchOf (source.subSequence(offset, source.length))) match {
       case Some(matched) => offset + matched.end
       case None => offset
     }
   else
     offset
```

so it skips whitespace (you can override this by overriding def skipWhitespace = false)

so for the parser `"          "` equals ""

whitespace tries to match "" but it fails ("""\s+""" requires at least one whitespace) and the **not** converts this in a success

Comment: Thanks, @Siphor. I actually asked this question as a follow-up to the implementation of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25294257/409976). I added `val nonWhitespaceRegex: Regex = "\\S+".r`, along with `guard(nonWhitespaceRegex) ~> ...` in order to verify that the `Input`, i.e. tokens that I was parsing, was not all whitespace. Otherwise, checking a bunch of whitespace to be EOF will return false.